# How to replicate web site files to web servers over WAN for LB sites?

Tags: centos, web-server, replication, wide-area-network

I am working on a new setup for a a handful of websites of mine.  My side business is growing (web hosting and light webdev) and I am working on a new infrastructure design using commodity hardware (i.e., cheap VPS providers).  These VPS's run CentOS 6.x on top of OpenVZ.

Basically, to start, I am looking at 3 VPS with ~50GB of storage each.  I want to have them behind a virtual NLB (AWS ELB, probably) and be tolerant of an outage of one of these VPS.  I will be running a combination of Pelican-based Static Sites, WordPress, and Drupal (using MariaDB) and some custom PHP-based applications (think CRUD-style inventory system).  Since I am using a NLB in front of these servers, I won't be able to control which server a customer might log into their WordPress site on, so I need file replication across all of these servers (starting with 3 servers, may grow up to as many as 6-10).  I've been looking at GlusterFS, but their Geo-Replication seems to be more of a DR solution providing one way replication.  I've also been looking at XtreemFS, and thinking this may be what I want.

Am I looking at the wrong products, and is their a better way to achieve what I am wanting to do?  Long story short, I plan to manage these with Ansible so I can easily roll out a new VPS and get it online in no-time, if need be.  Nginx is my front-end webserver for my sites, and I plan to use VirtualEnv for my Pelican sites (with VirtualEnv introduce any problems with file replication??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Wordpress uses a database, not web site files.
So you would need to set up MySQL multi-master replication.
There are numerous guides on the internet to do this.

For file replication for everything else, have you looked into rsync?

Comment: InnoDB is probably what I will use for the Database piece, so that shouldn't be a problem.

rsync is one way, which won't work for me.  (i.e., if a user logged into their Wordpress site on Server B, those changes won't be replicated to Server A.